# How to end a function if prompt answer is no in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

I wrote this function for a plug.dj script, it adds a chat message if the answer is yes, but I'm having trouble to end the function if the answer is no.  I am not a pro programmer.

Code:

```
f_votelggr: function (obj){
        if (nScript.mehShow) {
          if (obj.vote != 1) {
            prompt(obj.user.username + " didn't liked this song! Do you want to alert the users?")
            if ("yes");
            API.sendChat(obj.user.username + "didn't like this song!");                            
          } else {
            return
          };
    },
```

Comment: `return` would work just fine, but you're currently not using the result of the `prompt` call for anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ("no"){
    return null;
}
```

I guess this is what you are looking for. It will leave the function.

Edit:

```
 var input  = prompt(obj.user.username + " didn't liked this song! Do you want 
  to alert the users?")
  if (input == "yes"){
    API.sendChat(obj.user.username + "didn't like this song!");
   }                            
  else if{
        (input == "no"){
        // do stuff here
        return null;
    } else {
      return}
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the prompted input from user

```
 var input  = prompt(obj.user.username + " didn't liked this song! Do you want 
  to alert the users?")
  if (input == "yes"){
    API.sendChat(obj.user.username + "didn't like this song!");
   }                            
  else{
    return;
  };
```

And also you have

```
if ("yes");
```

Which terminates your if there right away. Remove that `;` and use `{}` just to avoid confusion and bugs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = prompt(obj.user.username + " didn't liked this song! Do you want to alert the users?");
input = input.toLowercase();
if (input === "yes") { 
  API.sendChat(obj.user.username + "didn't like this song!");
} else {
  return false;
};
```

Comment: plug.dj is a website where you can play songs and chat with other users,also there are some basic functions to automatize on the site,such as autowoot,join the dj booth,notify user join/leave,and the vote logger that i asked for help,i'm not planning to make this a big thing,it's just for the fun of coding and adding cool stuff to it